# Calculating statistics for defined grid cells in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst

I have a vector that defines the grid cells (black lines in attached image) and a raster dataset that contains landscape metrics for over 50,000 patches (in different columns in the attribute table). One of the landscape metrics is patch area. I want to calculate summary statistics (e.g. mean, majority/mode, median) for that specific landscape metric within each grid cell.

I've tried using zonal statistics but it doesn't seem to work, as there is no where I can select the 'Area' column for which the stats will be calculated.

[image: Dataset. The colors represent patch area (green = small area, red = large area)]

Comment: If your black lines represent POLYGONS and not LINES then the zonal stats tool _is_ the tool to be using, the zone field would be a unique ID for each polygon.

Comment: @Hornbydd Thanks for your suggestion. I just checked - they are indeed polygons. What I'm confused about is how does the zonal stats tool know which field/column in the 'input value raster' it will calculate the stats on? Is there any way of specifying this?

Answer (score 1):

[Zonal Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-statistics.htm) is the typical tool for your question. Since you have a polygon layer that defines the grid cells (Zones) and a raster layer of landscape, you can use `Zonal Statistics` to produce a new raster with the statistical info you want (`Mean, Majority, Maximum, Median, Minimum, Minority, Range, Std, Sum, Variety`).

Based on the above help `Input value raster` is

> Raster that contains the values on which to calculate a statistic

For example if you choose the Mean statistic type, the output zonal raster will calculate the mean of the pixel values of the input raster data within that zone.